# Alignment for fullPage.js vertical slider navigation dots

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins, fullpage.js

I am using a jquery plugin called fullPage.js.  It seems to be well documented, but I am having difficulty finding anything on the alignment of the navigation dots.  When I make them a bit larger (via css modifications), the alignment of the hover and active attributes gets thrown off.
Please see the fiddle below that contains the alignment error:
http://jsfiddle.net/pingo_/b1k9wt39/

I have also pasted the code on StackExchange, but it is not rendering the error (the dots do not seem to be sized larger):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#fullpage').fullpage({
    css3: true,
    navigation: true,
    navigationPosition: 'right',
    keyboardScrolling: true,
    controlArrows: true
  });
});
```

```css
#fp-nav ul li a.active span,
.fp-slidesNav ul li a.active span {
  background: #004e7b;
  position: absolute;
}
#fp-nav ul li a span,
.fp-slidesNav ul li a span {
  border: 1px solid #004e7b;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/jquery.fullPage.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/jquery.fullPage.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<body>
  <div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section" id="section0">
      <h2>B A N N E R</h2>

      <h3>Tagline</h3>

    </div>
    <div class="section" id="section1">
      <h2>Section 1</h2>

      <h3>Placeholder</h3>

    </div>
    <div class="section" id="section2">
      <h2>Section 2</h2>

      <h3>Placeholder</h3>

    </div>
    <div class="section" id="section3">
      <h2>Section 3</h2>

      <h3>Placeholder</h3>

    </div>
    <div class="section" id="section4">
      <h2>Section 4</h2>

      <h3>Placeholder</h3>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

If you remove the height and width code
`height: 10px; width: 10px;`
from my css in jsfiddle, you will see that the default setting aligns perfectly.  While this is nice, I would like the inactive dots to be the same size as the active one (more of a flatter/smoother design). Can anyone help me with this?  Something that can be done easily or a little more complex?

Thanks!

Comment: Should be ok now @SamuelLiew

Comment: Trying to get something similar to this: http://codyhouse.co/demo/vertical-fixed-navigation/  Saw something weird in the css that their threw me off: "  /* prevent weird movements on hover when you use a CSS3 transformation - webkit browsers */ "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be the CSS you need to fix the hover and active state:

```
#fp-nav ul li:hover a span,
.fp-slidesNav ul li:hover a span,
#fp-nav ul li a.active span, 
.fp-slidesNav ul li a.active span, 
#fp-nav ul li:hover a.active span,
.fp-slidesNav ul li:hover a.active span {
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    margin: -2px 0 0 -2px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b1k9wt39/4/

Comment: Thanks man !! Worked like a charm.  From a conceptual standpoint, would you mind explaining how you arrived there (as I am knew to this)? It seems you offset the upper and left margins by 2 px on the active and hover states.  Did you figure this out by testing, or is the something in that offsets it in the source css?  I noticed the -2px offset works for heghts and widths upwards of 20px.   Thanks again.

Comment: Those are the base styles for the default state. They can be found by inspecting the element. I then applied them to the hover and active states.